# ASP.NET maintain control state that has collection items

Tags: asp.net, generics, collections, custom-controls, state

Interesting. I have a control `QuickContacts` with `Contacts` collection. When I declare `Contacts` of type `List<Contact>` it works perfectly, but when use `ContactsList<Contact>` which is a Generic that implements `IList<T>` it gives "Parser Error : Type 'Controls.ContactList'1[[Controls.Contact, Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not have a public property named 'Contact'."
Here, this code works perfectly with `List<Contact>`

```
[DefaultProperty("Contacts"),
ParseChildren(true, "Contacts"),
ToolboxData("<{0}:QuickContacts runat=server></{0}:QuickContacts>")]
public class QuickContacts : WebControl
{
    private List<Contact> contactsList;

    [Category("Behavior"),
    Description("The contacts collection."),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(
        DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public List<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            if (contactsList == null)
            {
                contactsList = new List<Contact>();
            }
            return contactsList;
        }
    }
```

I want to provide a `Contacts` collection that maintains state so I replace using `List<Contacts>` with custom `ContactsList` that implements `IList<T>, IStateManager`. When use `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`, it doesn't work. Here is the

```
public class ContactList<T> : IList<T>, IStateManager
{
```

Then I use it as following:

```
[DefaultProperty("Contacts"),
ParseChildren(true, "Contacts"),
ToolboxData("<{0}:QuickContacts runat=server></{0}:QuickContacts>")]
public class QuickContacts : WebControl
{
    private ContactList<Contact> contactsList;

    [Category("Behavior"),
    Description("The contacts collection."),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(
        DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public ContactList<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            if (contactsList == null)
            {
                contactsList = new ContactList<Contact>();
            }
            return contactsList;
        }
    }
```

"Parser Error : Type 'Controls.ContactList'1[[Controls.Contact, Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not have a public property named 'Contact'."
Parser Error at `<cc1:Contact Name=`

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
    <cc1:QuickContacts ID="QuickContacts1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
        <cc1:Contact Name="someone" Email="someone@example.com"
        Phone="(555) 555-0100" />
```

I read many posts about `List<T>` vs `IList<T>` but that still doesn't answer the question. What difference between `List<T>` and a class that implements `IList<T>` which causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, when reviewed `List<T>` implementation at Microsoft [http://referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs)

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<>))]
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
[Serializable]
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
```

It implements `System.Collections.IList` too. And this was the point.

And here is the full working code.

```
[DefaultProperty("Contacts"),
ParseChildren(true, ChildrenAsProperties = true, DefaultProperty = "Contacts"),
ToolboxData("<{0}:QuickContacts runat=server></{0}:QuickContacts>")]
public class QuickContacts : WebControl
{
    private StateManagedCollection<Contact> contactsList;

    [Category("Behavior"),
    Description("The contacts collection."),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(
        DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public StateManagedCollection<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            if (contactsList == null)
            {
                contactsList = new StateManagedCollection<Contact>();
            }
            return contactsList;
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        Table t = CreateContactsTable();
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }

    private Table CreateContactsTable()
    {
        Table t = null;

        if (contactsList != null && contactsList.Count > 0)
        {
            t = new Table();

            foreach (Contact item in contactsList)
            {
                Contact aContact = item as Contact;

                if (aContact != null)
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
                    c1.Text = aContact.Name;
                    row.Controls.Add(c1);

                    TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
                    c2.Text = aContact.Email;
                    row.Controls.Add(c2);

                    TableCell c3 = new TableCell();
                    c3.Text = aContact.Phone;
                    row.Controls.Add(c3);

                    t.Controls.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }

        return t;
    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        if (savedState != null)
        {
            Pair p = savedState as Pair;
            base.LoadViewState(p.First);
            contactsList.LoadViewState(p.Second);
        }
    }

    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        Pair p = new Pair(base.SaveViewState(), contactsList.SaveViewState());
        return p;
    }

    protected override void TrackViewState()
    {
        base.TrackViewState();
        contactsList.TrackViewState();
    }
}
```

And here is the StateManagedCollection

```
    public class StateManagedCollection<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>, IStateManager
        where T : StateManagedClass, new()
{
    private List<T> lst = default(List<T>);
    private Boolean isTrackingViewState = default(Boolean);
    private Boolean saveAll = default(Boolean);

    public StateManagedCollection()
    {
        lst = new List<T>();
        isTrackingViewState = false;
        saveAll = false;
    }

    public void SetMarked()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            lst[i].SetMarked();
        }
    }

    public bool IsTrackingViewState
    {
        get { return isTrackingViewState; }
    }

    public void LoadViewState(object state)
    {
        if (state != null)
        {

            if (state is List<Object>)
            {
                // all items were saved

                List<Object> allItems = (List<Object>)state;
                saveAll = true;
                Int32 count = lst.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i < count)
                        lst[i].LoadViewState(allItems[i]);
                    else
                    {
                        T item = new T();
                        item.LoadViewState(allItems[i]);
                        lst.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (state is Dictionary<Int32, Object>)
            {
                Dictionary<Int32, Object> changedItems = (Dictionary<Int32, Object>)state;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<Int32, Object> item in changedItems)
                {
                    if (item.Key < lst.Count)
                        lst[item.Key].LoadViewState(item.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public object SaveViewState()
    {
        if (saveAll)
        {
            List<Object> allItems = new List<Object>();
            foreach (var item in lst)
            {
                item.SetMarked();
                allItems.Add(item.SaveViewState());
            }
            return allItems;
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<Int32, Object> changedItems = new Dictionary<Int32, Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
            {
                Object state = lst[i].SaveViewState();
                if (state != null)
                {
                    changedItems.Add(i, state);
                }
            }
            return changedItems;
        }
    }

    public void TrackViewState()
    {
        isTrackingViewState = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            lst[i].TrackViewState();
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return lst.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        lst.Insert(index, item);
        if (isTrackingViewState)
            saveAll = true;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        lst.RemoveAt(index);
        if (isTrackingViewState)
            saveAll = true;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return lst[index];
        }
        set
        {
            lst[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lst.Add(item);
        if (isTrackingViewState)
            saveAll = true;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lst.Clear();
        if (isTrackingViewState)
            saveAll = true;
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return lst.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        lst.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return lst.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        Boolean rslt = lst.Remove(item);
        if (isTrackingViewState)
            saveAll = true;
        return rslt;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return lst.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        Add((T)value);
        return Count - 1;
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        return Contains((T)value);
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return IndexOf((T)value);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        Insert(index, (T)value);
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return ((IList)lst).IsFixedSize; }
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        Remove((T)value);
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return lst[index];
        }
        set
        {
            lst[index] = (T)value;
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        CopyTo((T[])array, index);
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)lst).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)lst).SyncRoot; }
    }
}
```

And the StateManagedClass

```
public abstract class StateManagedClass : IStateManager
{
    private Boolean isTrackingViewState = default(Boolean);
    private StateBag viewState = default(StateBag);

    public StateManagedClass()
    {
        isTrackingViewState = false;
        viewState = new StateBag(false);
    }

    public virtual StateBag ViewState
    {
        get
        {
            return viewState;
        }
    }

    public bool IsTrackingViewState
    {
        get { return isTrackingViewState; }
    }

    public void LoadViewState(object state)
    {
        if (state != default(object))
        {
            ((IStateManager)viewState).LoadViewState(state);
        }
    }

    public object SaveViewState()
    {
        Object savedState = default(Object);

        if (viewState != null)
        {
            savedState =
                ((IStateManager)viewState).SaveViewState();
        }

        return savedState;
    }

    public void TrackViewState()
    {
        isTrackingViewState = true;

        if (viewState != default(StateBag))
        {
            ((IStateManager)viewState).TrackViewState();
        }
    }

    public void SetMarked()
    {
        viewState.SetDirty(true);
    }
}
```

And the Contact class

```
public class Contact : StateManagedClass 
{
    [
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(""),
    Description("Name of contact"),
    NotifyParentProperty(true)
    ]
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            Object s = ViewState["Name"];
            return (s == null) ? String.Empty : (String)s;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Name"] = value;
        }
    }

    [
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(""),
    Description("Email address of contact"),
    NotifyParentProperty(true)
    ]
    public String Email
    {
        get
        {
            Object s = ViewState["Email"];
            return (s == null) ? String.Empty : (String)s;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Email"] = value;
        }
    }

    [
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(""),
    Description("Phone number of contact"),
    NotifyParentProperty(true)
    ]
    public String Phone
    {
        get
        {
            Object s = ViewState["Phone"];
            return (s == null) ? String.Empty : (String)s;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Phone"] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Test the control:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/RTL.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm15.aspx.cs" Inherits="Controls.WebForm15" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Controls" Namespace="Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
    <cc1:QuickContacts ID="QuickContacts1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
        <cc1:Contact Name="someone" Email="someone@example.com"
            Phone="(555) 555-0100" />
        <cc1:Contact Name="jae" Email="jae@fourthcoffee.com"
            Phone="(555) 555-0101" />
        <cc1:Contact Name="lene" Email="lene@contoso.com"
            Phone="(555) 555-0102" />
    </cc1:QuickContacts>
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Refresh"></asp:Button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/WebForm15.aspx"
        runat="server">
    Reload Page</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="script" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

And the codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Controls
{
    public partial class WebForm15 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SkolaControlsWorkings.Controls.Contact contact = new SkolaControlsWorkings.Controls.Contact();
            contact.Name = "Name";
            contact.Email = "Email@mai.com";
            contact.Phone = "(111) 111-1111";
            QuickContacts1.Contacts.Add(contact);
            Button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can see how pressing the "Add" button causes new contact item to be added to the list, and how the new added contacts are maintained through page postbacks.
This is should be a complete working example, have fun.
Here is the MSDN original example [Web Control Collection Property Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x.aspx)